# Is there a quick way to assign multiple class variables using constructor arguments in Java?

Tags: java, constructor

If we have an object with a bunch of attributes, is there a simple way to assign these effectively in the constructor?

For example, in the following class, I have three lines in the constructor to simply pass along data.

```
class XYZ {
    int x, y, z;
    XYZ(int x, int y, int z) {
         this.x = x;   
         this.y = y;   
         this.z = z;   
    }
}
```

Is there a more effective way (in the case that you have even more variables)? I know of the `Builder` approach. Not really what I am looking for, here.

By effective, I mean less and cleaner code. Now, there is a lot of boilerplate code. I was just wondering if there was a smarter way to do this.

Comment: define effective, what exactly are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Updated my question. Hope this helps. It just seems like a lot of DRY violation to me (and a lot of typing if you have a lot of attributes).

Comment: @MWB but there is no repeating code

Comment: You might want to look at other JVM languages, Groovy supports a "quicker way", others might, too

Comment: I am not sure if anything in Groovy has made it's way into more recent Java versions.. But with Groovy you could do things like send in key/value pairs - somewhat analagous to JSON (or dictionary/map in various languages). I think this may be what OP is eluding to. So it's a valid question in my eyes.

Comment: It's not repeating code, basically. It's "boilerplate". You can use lombok or similar libraries. IDE can also generate constructors, setters, getters etc. for you

Answer (score 1):

In Java, you have to initialize each parametrized Value in the constructor. 
I don't see how this is not effective.
If you happen to have even more variables, you should definitely look again at the builder pattern, otherwise, when your object becomes complex, you can create embedded Objects in your class.

Also if you just want to have a clean code in your editor, please have a look at the lombok project: https://projectlombok.org/features/constructor

It will create the constructor at compilation time and you have a clean code.

```
@AllArgsConstructor
public class XYZ {
  private int x, y, z;
}
```

Comment: You could have an annotation processor that does the same (generate a constructor) in java too.  The annotation could also mention a specific list of fields for the constructor, and its visibility.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have more than 3 arguments to pass to the constructor, a good practice would be to group them in a class.

So instead of passibg 9 primitive args to your constructor, you will pass 3 object containing 3 primitive for example.

The cost here is that your will create additional object. However that cost should be reasonably low with the jdk9 and beyondq